# No me crea ninguna interfaz grafica al ejecutar el programa python

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy haciendo una interfaz gráfica de un programa, acabo de empezar y ya me está dando problemas. 
En la interfaz solo aparece un texto y dos botones, el problema es que al ejecutar el programa no se me abre ninguna ventana grafica ni nada. Dejo el código por si hay algún error que no detecto:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3

#-----------PANTALLA INICIO Y CREAR CUENTA------------
raiz=Tk()

frameInicio=Frame(raiz, width=500, height=500)
frameInicio.pack()

labelBienvenida=Label(frameInicio, text="BIENVENIDO AL GESTOR DE ALMACÉN")
labelBienvenida.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

inicioSesion=Button(frameInicio, text="Iniciar sesión")
inicioSesion.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

crearCuenta=Button(frameInicio, text="Crear cuenta")
crearCuenta.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya he descubierto mi error, me faltaba el raiz.mainloop()

Comment: Excelente Diego, te sugiero agregues una explicación de acuerdo a [ask] y nos ayude a toda la comunidad tu respuesta, saludos!